# How do I take the parent divs height and use it for a child div that has position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have a situation in which I have a child div (`.timeline`) that needs to increase height as the parent divs (`.tea-history`) height increases. But when I tried using `height:inherit;` it did not work since the child div inherits height as auto from the parent div, when I tried doing it with `height:100%;` it would use the height of the entire page.

Anyone got an idea on how this could be fixed so the `.timeline` class will increase height when the parent div increases height.

```css
.tea-history {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  height: 800px; /*Currently i have set the height to 800 so the timeline is visible*/
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.tea-history .timeline {
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  width: 3px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #7aaa62;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.tea-history .frame {
  width: 80%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto;
  gap: 33px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 42px;
}

.tea-history .frame .timeline-dot {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.tea-history .timeline-dot .outer-dot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #000 solid 3px;
}

.tea-history .timeline-dot .inner-dot {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tea-history">
  <h3 class="heading">History</h3>
  <div class="timeline"></div>
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="timeline-dot"><span class="outer-dot"><span class="inner-dot"></span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>2035 - 2054</h4>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam. Volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus. Nec nam aliquam sem
        et tortor consequat. Ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id. Egestas diam in arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh. Elit eget gravida cum sociis natoque. Nunc lobortis mattis aliquam
        faucibus purus in. Turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper. Imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your child's div class or id that you need to increase height as the parent div, tell both class names too?

Comment: I mentioned it in the edit, the parent div is ```.tea-history``` and the child div is ```.timeline```

Comment: Place `position: relative` on the parent and then any absolutely positioned child elements will be relative to it, so you can use percentage heights on them.

Comment: Is it not set to relative by default ? This was the only thing i didn't try yet since I thought its relative by default

Comment: By default [elements are `position: static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#formal_definition)

Comment: in addition to position:relative, use height:100% with the absolute element

Answer (score 0):

Because **absolute** positioned elements are removed from the flow and ignored by other elements. So you can't set the parents height according to an absolutely positioned element that's why `inherit` didn't work.

You either **have to use fixed heights or you need to involve JS**.

And here is a tricky way to do it:

Duplicate the content of `.tea-history` and .`timeline` in relative divs with `display:none` value in parent div. So let's say `.tea-history_duplicate` and `.timeline_duplicate`. Put `.timeline_duplicate` on top and `.tea-history_duplicate` at the bottom.

When your jquery calls the absolute div, just set the according to relative div (`.timeline_duplicate` or `.timeline_duplicate`) with the property of `display:block;` and `visibility:hidden;`. The relative child will still be invisible but will make the parent's div higher.

Comment: Involving js is not a option as this needs to be done with HTML and CSS only. Thank you for your solution, i will try using it.

Comment: I just add another way, take a look at this too.

Comment: It would work but unfortunately, JS and jQuery are not allowed in this project since its a CSS only

Comment: oh well if that's the case then you have to think of a more tricky way to do it, all the best and I hope you find a solution to your problem, and if I get any other ideas I will share it here too. have a great time.